# Reading from file in a loop

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to read from a file with a buffer of 255 bytes.

```
li $v0, 13                  # open a file
li $a1, 0                   # file flag (read)
la $a0, filename            # load file name
add $a2, $zero, $zero       # file mode (unused)
syscall

loop:               # loop through the bytes until the # of bytes read is zero or an error
move $a0, $v0               # load file descriptor
li $v0, 14                  # read from file
la $a1, textBuffer          # allocate space for the bytes loaded
li $a2, 255                 # number of bytes to be read
syscall

blez $v0, loop_done     # is # of bytes read zero or an error?

la $a0, textBuffer          # address of string to be printed
li $v0, 4                   # print string
syscall

j loop

loop_done:

li $v0, 16
syscall             # close file
```

However it is just printing the first 255 bytes, not the entire content of the file. I am not sure how to move the position over when reading a file, if it isn't automatically done.

textBuffer and filename are

```
filename: .asciiz "data.txt"
textBuffer: .word 255
```

in the data section

Comment: `textBuffer: .word 255` is wrong, that only allocates a single word with value 255, not 255 bytes. Try `.space 255` instead. Also you should probably use the `write` syscall to write as many bytes as you have read, not the `write string` which writes until the first zero byte.

Comment: `move $a0, $v0` is inside your `loop:` meaning that on the second iteration, `$a0` has the value 4, not the file descriptor as you intend.